# Elastic search collapse and aggregation count issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I have collapse data using one attribute and aggregation for layered navigation price, it is showing result correct but count is wrong due to collapse

example: We have 2 document in price range 3000-4000 both document attribute value same which attribute data collapsed

so as of now showing 2 count instead of 1.

any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Collapsing is applied to the top hits only and does not affect aggregations. docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html#collapse-search-results

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behaviour for the collapse because distinct count is unknown and same you can read in [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html#collapse-search-results) as well:

> The total number of hits in the response indicates the number of
> matching documents without collapsing. The total number of distinct
> group is unknown.

Also, As Jaspreet mentioned in comment:

> Collapsing is applied to the top hits only and does not affect
> aggregations.